# Spring MVC redirect with custom http headers

Tags: spring-mvc

I am developing small spring mvc app where user needs to be redirected to external application with some http headers. Say for eg. user is on application 1 on url
http://localhost:8080/app1. On this app we have simple jsp page with some forms and user fill it up. After that we need to collect this data on form submit and redirect user to another external app on url like http://localhost:9090/app2

Now when this redirect happens, we need to maintain or add http headers. Since redirect is fresh new request from browser, it is loosing headers added in app 1 before being redirected.

Here is sample code which adds headers in app 1 before being redirected to app2

```
    response.addHeader("userId","test");
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9090/app2");
```

When I go check the browser developer tools, i dont see header when it lands on app2. Can anyone tell how to fix this?

Comment: The headers you add to a **response** are not automatically added to the next **request** by the browser. There is no way to do what you want with headers. But you can add a query string to the URL you redirect to.

Comment: Yes, query string works for me. But wanted to confrim about my understanding of redirect with headers and both you(JB Nizet) and lane.maxwell confirmed that. Thank for your quick response guys.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct in that the headers will not forward.  One surefire way to pull this off would be to place these data into a cookie.

Comment: any alternate , i undestand we can send as query paramter but here is a certain restriction on length right do headers seems to be solution.