# Java Rest Spring redirecting with custom httpheaders

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 spring boot based java app .

In one of the controller i am redirecting to call to second app but second app is also expecting some request headers. How can i add requestheaders to redirect uri.

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> testMethod(@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String userAgent){

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

// validating request .if success 

headers.set("test-header", "value");
URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8083/test1");
headers.setLocation(uri);
return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);
}
```

but in the second app i don't see headers coming in . Is there a way to redirect with http headers.

Please help me out.

Comment: try to set in your application.properties `server.use-forward-headers=true`

Comment: @Glim tried did not work

i only see 
key :hostvalue :localhost:8083
key :connectionvalue :keep-alive
key :upgrade-insecure-requestsvalue :1
key :user-agentvalue :Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
key :acceptvalue :text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
key :dntvalue :1
key :accept-encodingvalue :gzip, deflate, br
key :accept-languagevalue :en-US,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7
key :cookievalue :_ga=GA1.1.1236633073.1520536474

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an "Accept:" header on Spring RestTemplate request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request)

Comment: @MehrajMalik , that will work fine with RestTemplate but I am redirecting the call to different app. So , both the scenarios are different .

Comment: use cookie or query params instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523670/spring-mvc-redirect-with-custom-http-headers